# how to set "min" and "max" value for Field in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, redux-form

Input type being date and have something similar to this :

```
 <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
```

Answer (score 1):

So man, that is it. Just close your tag:

```js
<Field
   name="trip-start"
   component={<input
    type="date"
    value="2018-07-22"
    min="2018-01-01"
    max="2018-12-31"
   />}
/>
```

Comment: Ow, sorry! Try Field component with attribute ``component``